# How to stop Android Studio's code completion from writing redundant qualifier when calling the Surface composable?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I type `Surf` and summon the code-completion's suggestion of calling the `Surface` composable function, it writes the whole package name of the composable before it: `androidx.compose.material.Surface` instead of just `Surface`, since `androidx.compose.material` is a redundant qualifier. I already have `androidx.compose.material.Surface` properly imported. It's not happening with other composables under the same  package like `Text` and `TextField`. It's pretty annoying. How do I make it so that the auto-completion will only write `Surface`?[image]

Comment: this looks like Android Studio bug, report it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue in the latest Bumblebee as of now. Update to the latest version.

EDIT: It IS a bug in BumbleBee Canary 8. File a bug at the issue-tracker

Comment: ooh, great, but I only use the stable version. I'll check it out one day tho. thanks

Comment: Canary versions, or as that matter of fact, any preview versions are not deadly. They are made available to the developers only after testing. Give 'em a try, they expose the latest features far before the general public sees them. Compose is been around for I guess two years in the canary builds? Many have even learned its concepts far before people knew it existed. Keep up

Comment: I'm aware that it's not deadly, tho the last time I tried the Canary channel, it had some pretty serious bugs, so I went back and stuck with the stable release.